Troubleshooting npm ERR! code 1 Errors During Package Installation
My project is built on Laravel and Vue.js. I'm encountering the following error (shown in the picture). I've tried several solutions, including deleting node_modules and package-lock.json followed by running npm install, but the error persists. I also tried removing node-sass with npm remove node-sass, but when i run this command I get the same errors. I've tried clearing the npm cache using npm cache clean --force but the error persists.
I have Python installed and its path set in the environment variables, but it's not working.
    {
        "private": true,
        "scripts": {
            "dev": "npm run development",
            "development": "mix",
            "watch": "mix watch",
            "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
            "hot": "mix watch --hot",
            "prod": "npm run production",
            "production": "mix --production"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "@johmun/vue-tags-input": "^2.1.0",
            "@pencilpix/vue2-clock-picker": "^0.1.6",
            "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.20.3",
            "@trevoreyre/autocomplete-vue": "^2.2.0",
            "@vee-validate/i18n": "^4.5.3",
            "axios": "^0.19.2",
            "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
            "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
            "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
            "core-js": "^3.19.0",
            "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
            "echarts": "^4.9.0",
            "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
            "jspdf": "^2.3.0",
            "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.23",
            "jspdf-html2canvas": "^1.4.9",
            "laravel-mix": "^6.0.41",
            "lodash.orderby": "^4.6.0",
            "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.5.3",
            "mobile-device-detect": "^0.4.3",
            "moment": "^2.29.1",
            "moment-locales-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.0",
            "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
            "targets-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
            "vee-validate": "^3.4.5",
            "vue": "^2.6.12",
            "vue-barcode": "^1.3.0",
            "vue-clickaway": "^2.2.2",
            "vue-cookie": "^1.1.4",
            "vue-cookies": "^1.7.4",
            "vue-easy-print": "0.0.8",
            "vue-echarts": "^5.0.0-beta.0",
            "vue-excel-xlsx": "^1.2.2",
            "vue-flag-icon": "^1.0.6",
            "vue-good-table": "^2.21.11",
            "vue-html-to-paper": "^1.4.4",
            "vue-i18n": "^8.26.5",
            "vue-image-lightbox-carousel": "^1.0.7",
            "vue-lazyload": "^1.3.3",
            "vue-loader": "^15.9.8",
            "vue-localstorage": "^0.6.2",
            "vue-meta": "^2.4.0",
            "vue-mj-daterangepicker": "^0.1.11",
            "vue-navigation-bar": "^4.1.0",
            "vue-perfect-scrollbar": "^0.2.1",
            "vue-router": "^3.5.3",
            "vue-select": "^3.16.0",
            "vue-simple-spinner": "^1.2.10",
            "vue-sweetalert2": "^3.0.8",
            "vue-upload-multiple-image": "^1.1.6",
            "vue2-daterange-picker": "^0.6.8",
            "vue2-editor": "^2.10.3",
            "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.6.2",
            "vuex": "^3.6.0"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
            "@vue/composition-api": "^1.2.4",
            "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
            "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
            "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
            "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.4.1",
            "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
            "postcss-loader": "^6.2.1",
            "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
            "sass": "^1.49.7",
            "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
            "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
            "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.5.0",
            "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
            "webpack-i18n-extractor-plugin": "^2.0.7"
        }
    }


Please don't post images of code or errors!

remove the images and copy/paste the text instead.  also paste the contents of package.json and what version of node you have installed.

What happens if you type python2 in your terminal? If it errors try to reinstall it.

it give python2  is not recognized as an internal or external command

i am using node 20.0.0

Time to remove everything you can to python and reinstall it properly.

I have already reinstall the python and set it path again but not working

Reboot your computer maybe. Otherwise, it means that you did not properly install it. Did you followed the official docs?
